# Tags for geographical zones

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

As well as [Tagging geographical areas](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/tagging-geographic-areas) we should also make tags for geographical zones:

- [tropic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropic)
- [polar](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polar)
- [temperate](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperate) (just to be complete, but actually not needed I think)

I think especially the [tropic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropic) and [polar](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polar) tags are needed to denote special (for us unusual, extreme) conditions needed to consider for that particular question, like:

"How to keep my electronics from humidity in tropics?"

"Wild camping in tropics"

Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a good suggestion - for questions where climate matters. It shouldn't be mandatory for all questions (like the question about navigating in fog; fog is fog, no matter where you are). Extreme temperature zones definitely warrant special considerations, but not every question here needs to specify what the climate is.

Comment: Laura, completely agree - my motivation is to use these tags to mark activities in tropical / polar zones, not for all questions, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that these broad geographic tags can and should be used, but only when the answer applies to at least most of the zone, as I describe in [my answer here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/66/18).

Comment: well, depends on a question - I may ask some more general question but as I go to Cuba, I put it in a special context. Then I may also add tag [tag:tropic] to attract people subscribed to this broader tag, who might help me from more general point of view.